# is there any way other than ftp ,HTTP to download/Upload files using obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload, download

is there any way other than ftp ,HTTP to download/upload files using obj c for an iphone app,thanx in advance

Comment: download/upload files from what? If its a standard web service then http/ftp protocols are the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any protocol that both your app and the party on the other end understand. FTP and HTTP just happen to be the most widely spoken protocols.

Answer (score 0):

There's [CFSocket](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html)/[NSStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Not sure it's worth the headache. I'd stick with the more common protocols (HTTP/FTP) unless there's a glaring need to go with something else.

Comment: It's not that hard if you know the basics of streams. I did it the last few days and implemented a simple FTP client on Mac. ;-)

Comment: @Sandro Meier: It's not *that* hard, but it isn't worth the headache in a lot of cases cases, since just using HTTP is even less hard.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're interested in TFTP, here's a library you could use http://sourceforge.net/projects/tftp/